# Create a correlation graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot, correlation

I'm trying to emulate this graph:  [image]

If I have a correlation matrix how can I create an output like this?

Comment: Looks like output of the command imagesc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an `n x n` correlation matrix `M`, and a vector `L` of length `n` containing the label for each bin, you can use something like the following:

```
imagesc(M); % plot the matrix
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:n); % center x-axis ticks on bins
set(gca, 'YTick', 1:n); % center y-axis ticks on bins
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', L); % set x-axis labels
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', L); % set y-axis labels
title('Your Title Here', 'FontSize', 14); % set title
colormap('jet'); % set the colorscheme
colorbar on; % enable colorbar
```

Rotating x-axis labels is not trivial, but the MATLAB Central File Exchange contains [some solutions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722).

Comment: For x-axis label rotation, you can easily do it via matlab figure window: 1. select *show plot tools and dock figures* button from toolbar, https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmiz1.png 2. click on x-axis labels on figure https://i.stack.imgur.com/63oKg.png 3. choose *more propertises...* from the appeared window https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8NRm.png 4. Navigate to *XTickLabelRotation* and set it 90.0 https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHjz7.png

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Thomas C. G.'s answer, I'd use:

```
imagesc(myMatrix);
colormap(jet);
colorbar;

% then to set the axis titles you'll have to use
% Please note the curly braces for the cell array
labelNames = {'USA','NASDAQ','Dow Jones'};
set(gca,'XTickLabel',labelNames);   % gca gets the current axis
set(gca,'YTickLabel'labelNames);   % gca gets the current axis
```

Unfortunately, AFAIK, making the text labels vertical as they are in your figure [is a bit harder](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15TK6/index.html?solution=1-15TK6).  Maybe somebody else has knowledge to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

To plot a matrix as an image you just need to call two functions:

```
image(myMatrix)
colormap(jet)
```

The [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) function defines the colour pattern used to render the image. The image you posted is using the "jet" colormap.

And to show the colour scale beside the image use the [colorbar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colorbar.html) function.