# Correlation map with an overlaid opacity

Tags: python, matlab, graphics, matplotlib, overlay

I'd like to create a correlation map (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388940/create-a-correlation-graph-in-matlab)) with an overlaid opacity, defined for each point (such as the correlation maps in the top left corner [here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v508/n7495/carousel/nature13186-f4.jpg)), as I would like to show statistically significant correlations only. Is there a way to do this in Matlab or Python (matplotlib)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `'AlphaData'` attribute of the plot

```
 % generate random data for example
 A = rand(30); 
 A = A.*A'; %//'
 msk = A > .5; % choose values not to be masked
 figure;
 ih = imagesc(A); 
 set(ih, 'AlphaData', msk );
 axis([ 1 30 1 30 ] );
```

And the result:
[image]